# Will Dragon Boat Be Changed to Loong Boat?

Tags: translation, culture

Recently news reports in China said the English version of 龙年 lunar new year of dragon has been changed into year of loong, to distinguish the auspicious animal of China from the evil monster of the West.

Will there be a chain reaction? Will 龙船 become loong boat and 端午节 Loong Boat Festival?

Comment: I would have expected they would use Hanyu Pinyin which would be spelled Long. But then I guess there is a risk the boats could be confused with the Viking ships which used to raid the English coast, or the Thai boats with extremely long outboard motors.

Comment: when  the communist **legally** change china to zhongguo  & themshelf to gongchandang 

Comment: I was from Hong Kong, and this kind of thing worries me. Will Victoria Habor become Xi Jinping Habor?

Comment: To quote a phrase from a much disliked colonial master, "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet"

Comment: We'll know they are serious when they get around to renaming Queen's Road :-)

Comment: @WayneCheah That said, should you call your biological father Uncle No. 3 or 三叔, you definitely would get your ass caned in your childhood or your heritage to his estate disowned in your adulthood.

Comment: @NanningYouth In certain times in the past when superstition was rife among rural ethnic communities, there were actual cases where they called their biological parents by some other form of addresses in order to ward off evil influences by "confusing" whatever malevolent spirit plaguing the family. By not calling your father "father" the evil spirit thought your father is dead. This of course is not a common practice. Much like Chinese temples have a low barrier at the front door in the belief that evil spirits lacking human agility couldn't stride over the barrier and enter the temple.